# Got an npm install Error 403 Forbidden in my CI pipeline

Tags: npm, gitlab-ci, npm-install, artifactory

the `npm install` failed with the following 403 error message

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://<my-private-jforg-registry>/zone.js/-/zone.js-0.13.1.tgz
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
```

I am using the following .npmrc configuration in my CI environment:

```
registry=https://<my-private-jforg-registry>
//<my-private-jforg-registry>:_password=${CI_NPM_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}
//<my-private-jforg-registry>:username=${CI_NPM_REGISTRY_USERNAME}
//<my-private-jforg-registry>:${CI_NPM_REGISTRY_MAIL}
//<my-private-jforg-registry>:always-auth=true
```

why npm is trying to retrieve `zone.js`from my private registry ?

when I do `npm whoami` I can see that I'm loggedin successfuly, I already cleaned the npm cache

Any suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

If You use a virtual repository and Jfrog doesn't find your package, it checks the local repository. I think this repo doesn't have permissions.